# conjugates of upper-triangular matrices have common eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A,B,U \in SL_2(F)$. If $A$ and $B$ are upper-triangular matrices, then prove that
$U^{-1}AU$ and $U^{-1}BU$ have common a eigenvector.

I know is that $[1,0]^t$ is a common eigenvector of $A$ and $B$. Any idea?

Comment: You changed $A$ and $B$ using $U$, so why not try and think of a way to change $[1,0]$ using $U$.

Comment: I tried it. We can multiply $Av=sv$ from the left by $U^{-1}$ but it is not possible multiply the equation from the right by $U$.

Comment: You were on the right lines, but multiplying the eigenvector equation directly won't give what you want.  Another idea is to think about what $U^{-1}AU$ does: if $A$ is the matrix of a linear map with respect to the standard basis then $U^{-1}AU$ is the matrix of that linear map with respect to a different basis.  What is $[1,0]^t$ in this new basis?

Comment: $U^{-1}AU(U^{-1}v)=s(U^{-1}v)$

Comment: Got it :) So $U^{-1}[1,0]^t$ is the eigenvector